can anyone help me in writing a quartet
hi i've been doing some analyzing and after learning counterpoint and 4 part harmony and studying a little about forms today for the first time i wrote a period to turn in into a ternary or a simple piece
can anyone help me realize the mistakes i have made? ( beside the direct motion into perfect interval by step that i allowed myself to have)
are the legatos correct

?
can a quartet atually play it ?
i would be so thankful

"are the legatos right?": How might they be wrong?  The choice of legato or other articulation is purely at your discretion.  Are you asking whether they are technically possible?  Whether they are notated correctly?  Something else?

Sorry for the confusion my grammar is bad , i meant is it correct technically ? ,because i assume that   notes that are on adjacent strings can't literally be played legato ?

Looks OK to me. I wonder what's up with all the staccato dots though. Do you really want staccato notes there, or just not legato? The staccato dots under the last full-bar notes make no sense. BTW string instruments can very well play legato over adjacent strings.

there are some wrongly staccatos that i forgot to erase and fix in the App .  thanks for the information on legato i thought it's same as playing classical guitar that switching strings disrupts the legato . also i could really use some advice of you experts on developing this idea

Please consider reposting this in The Auditorium, which is a chat room for the purpose of sharing and/or critiquing compositions and performances.

Hi! Please read about how to keep questions and answers focused. (Maybe also about the topics covered here.) A general "please tell me about any problems here" question is too broad. There are several great questions contained or implied within, though, like "can string instruments slur across different strings" (yes, and they can use fingering strategies to avoid the string changes too). I suggest using the "edit" button to focus on one of these questions, or opening several new ones.

The grammar is perfectly fine (aside from the lack of punctuation, which is relatively easy to deal with here but sometimes has a more negative effect); it's just an ambiguity inherent in the question "are the legatos right" :-)

I’m voting to close this question because rather than evaluate and advise on original compositions on the main site, we created The Auditorium for such discussions.


...for the first time i wrote

That's great. Keep it up!

...can anyone help me realize the mistakes i have made? ( beside the direct motion into perfect interval by step that i allowed myself to have)

My first reaction to that is: don't ask for voice leading checks from others and then waffle about allowing yourself certain violations. Actual classical music does have occasional parallel or direct motion and certainly such motion abounds in modern styles. It isn't a matter whether it is "ok." You can do whatever you like. Stand by your work. If you are still working to master voice leading, relative motion stuff, try your utmost to write well on those points and make revisions to fix problems.
I would rework the direct octaves in mm. 3, 11 at the least as an exercise. I assume the soprano line is your primary concern. So, the "fix" to work through is: keep the D5 in soprano, make the bass take an F, which will fix the outer voice direct motion problem, then reassign the pitches for violin 2 and viola, probably move violin 2 down to D4 and have viola hold the A3. That would at least get us to the D chord in m.3, after that I didn't really check. Sometimes fixes like this lead to subsequent problems. But that's another issue.

... i wrote a period to turn in into a ternary or a simple piece...

I think this is a nice idea; to start small and practice working up the size.
To get the classical design for a simple ternary, such as a minuet (or other similar dance_ with trio and da capo, use this basic layout of sections and repeats:


Dance

||: I (8 bars) V :||: (8 bars) I :||

Trio (often in the key of the subdominant or parallel minor)

||: I (8 bars) V :||: (8 bars) I :||

Da capo repeat of first dance without repeats. 
Usually this is indicated with the words "minuet da capo" at the end of the trio.


So, just add the repeat signs to demark your sections mm. 1-8 and mm. 9-16 and you have a good first half for a small ternary form. For the trio, here are some things to consider:

reuse a motif or small melodic segment from the first dance
try a texture change, ex. your main dance has vn1, vn2, vla in parallel motion in eighths m. 3 and m. 11, in the trio try breaking up that two eighth note figure from parallel to each of the three voices in turn over three measures.
"standing on the dominant" harmony is common for trio sections

A trio doesn't need to be completely new material. You can build the trio out using material from the main dance.
If you think you might try to go from a ternary form for quartet to trying the other movements of a quartet (like sonata, andante, rondo, etc.), it might be good to make your next ternary form in 3/4 time as a minuet, because this is one of the standard movements in a quartet.

Writing a quartet is a challenging task, especially considering the vast repertoire left by the great composers of the past.
My advice would be:

Expand your musical library: Listen to as many quartets as you can to understand different styles and approaches.
Find a music teacher: If you want to compose, improving your theoretical and compositional skills is essential. The subjects you might want to study include music history, music theory, harmony, counterpoint, and analysis.
Focus on music history: Understanding music history is crucial because it helps you know where you stand as a composer and how you can contribute to the tradition.

